# "Committer" in the context of software development

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, software

I stumbled across the following [StackOverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2938/jasonsmith) and keep wondering how to translate the word

> committer

like in the following sentence

> Apache CouchDB committer and Node.js developer.

The context is someone, who commits to a piece of code to a repository in version control system like Git. It's also different to a maintainer, who is in charge of a repository.

Comment: I would do, what was done thousand times before: Use the english technical term in German as it is, without translation: Since it is a profession, it will appear in two genders, for male and female persons: Male: »Der Committer», female: »die Committerin«.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but it sounds a little weird to me. Just like "gedebugt" oder "geinterupptet". Maybe there's a better option...

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: It is not a profession, it's just a job. Committerin ist Quatsch, der geschlechtslose Begriff heißt einfach Committer. Übersetzung wäre: "Versionseinpflegender", was unter Programmierern kein Mensch sagt und ziemlich gut deutlich macht, dass der engl. Begriff schon falsch gewählt ist, da gemeint ist, es handelt sich um einen, der vom Projekt das Privileg des Schreibzugriffs aufs Repository bekommen hat. Besser sollte dort "active developer" stehen, also "aktiv Mitwirkender" oder so ähnlich, also jemand, der auch direkt am Produkt mitprogrammieren darf.

Comment: +1 äöü. Nobody outside the English speaking hacker 'hood understands "committer" correctly. That's a lot of people, still you can't leave it alone when translating into a German text. It's not in any dictionary. Please see http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/committer and http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=committer on the term. Ugh! "Committer" in reality means "developer of the project" and "developer" means "contributor from outside".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a German native speaker and software developer I recommend using the word "Committer" in German as well. It's well-known and there is no proper translation in this context.

In a profile like those on SO you could also use the more formal word "Mitwirkender", which means "contributor".

Comment: The German Wikipedia page calls it "committer", too.

Comment: +1 I like "Mitwirkender". How would you fit it in the sentence mentioned above?

Comment: Mitwirkender an Apache CouchDB und Node.js Entwickler. (female: "Mitwirkende" and "Entwicklerin")

Comment: As a software developer who studies German professionally, I would say C.L. is right, because I've faced it in German language either, other examples:  "MVC" (Model View Controller, strukturiertes Software-Architekturmuster ) "Editor" or "HTML Editor", "CMS" (Content management System), "WPF" (Windows Presentation Foundation) in German language.

Answer (score 1):

Mir scheint, die bisherigen Übersetzungsvorschläge haben den Kern der Sache noch nicht ganz getroffen. Das wesentliche Merkmal eines "Committers" (hier und in der Verwendung, wie ihn die Wikipedia beschreibt,) ist nicht, dass er "(aktiv) mitwirkt" oder "Versionen einpflegt", sondern, dass er, wie schon an anderer Stelle hier erwähnt, Schreibzugriff hat. Entsprechend sollte man in der Übersetzung nicht das "Beitragen/Tun", sondern das "Können" hervorheben. Mir erscheint deshalb die Benennung "Revisionsberechtigter" als recht zweckdienlich, wenn man ausschließlich den Aspekt des "Committens" in den Vordergrund stellen möchte (wie es auch der englische Begriff tut) und nicht etwa andere Funktionen einer Person, die "committet".

Comment: Anderswo heißt das _Redakteur_, _Manager_, _Superviser_, _Controller_, _Gatekeeper_, _Mod/Moderator_, _Polier_, _Schichtleiter_, _UvD_, _Hauswart_, _Obmann_, _Klassensprecher_ ...